# Generating dependencies for a makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use a makefile to generate assets for web application. I have a script which generates dependencies for a given CSS or JS file as a list of filenames. How can I modify it and use in makefile?

UPD: Here's what I came up with for CSS. It's tailored for our workflow, we use lots of CSS imports in development environment.

```
#CSS_SRCs should contain only import directives
CSS_SRC = base.css base-inner.css
CSS_MIN = $(CSS_SRC:.css=.min.css)
#CSS compression tool of your choice 
CSS_COMPRESSOR=cat

%.min.css:
    $(CSS_COMPRESSOR) $^ > $@

all: $(CSS_MIN)

%.d: %.css
    rm -f $@; \
    printf '$*.min.css $@: ' >> $@; \
    sed -e 's|@import url(\"\([^\"]*\)\");|\1|' $< | tr '\n' ' '>> $@

include $(CSS_SRC:.css=.d)
```

With JavaScripts it's a little bit trickier cause I need to pull dependencies out of Google Closure library.

Comment: What is the format of the list? One line, with filenames separated by some delimiter? Or each filename on a separate line?

Comment: @Beta Newline is a delimiter isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Write the dependencies out as 'make' rules, and then include the file in the Makefile.

Comment: Well, the question is how exactly I can do that. Guides I've seen are targeted for advanced users and/or C-developers.

Comment: It depends entirely on what technologies you're using - what scripting language, what flavour of make, etc.